# Not able to intracting with smartcontract with javascript to get useraddress and smartcontract balance

Tags: javascript, frontend, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

Hi am new to blockchain technology i have made a smart contract that will show contract balance and user data like his address, balance, and user can deposit inserted amount in smartcontract my code is down am not able to show neither contract balance nor user data. its working perfectly in remix.

smartcontract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

contract UserData {

    address owner;
    uint bal;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function getBalance() view public returns(uint) {
        return bal;
    }

    function deposit(uint amt) external payable {
        bal = bal + amt;
        bal += msg.value;
    }

    // function to get the useraddress
    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {    
        return owner;
    }
    
    // Function to return current balance of user
    function getUserBalance() public view returns(uint256){
        return owner.balance;
    }

    function withdraw(uint withdrawAmount) external payable {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can withdraw!");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(withdrawAmount);
    }
}
```

and here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
var contract;

$(document).ready(function(){
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    //ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

    var address = "0xd3553504e02681C4d4f1969017dAca11003bB496";
    var abi = [];

    contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

    contract.methods.getBalance().call().then(function(bal){
        $('#balance').html(bal/10000000000000000);
    })

    contract.methods.getOwner().call().then(function(address){
        $('#userAddress').html(address);
    })

})

$('#deposit').click(function(){
    var amt = 0;
    amt = parseInt($('#amount').val());

    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(accounts){
        var acc = accounts[0];
        return contract.methods.deposit(amt).send({from: acc});
    }).then(function(tx){
        console.log(tx);
    }).catch(function(tx){
        console.log(tx);
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question is not specific. You can check this repository that contains videos of related topics. I'm sure you'll find your answer here.
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js

Comment: This is not a solution , Please try to put direct solutions than redirecting user to some other solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).